# Determine minimum selling price based on cost and fees

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'm sure that this is a really simple equation but I just can't seem to wrap my brain around it.  I am trying to find out a minimum selling price based of the following:

Product Cost + Shipping Cost + Fees (% based on Minimum Sales Price) = Minimum Selling Price

The fees are based on the selling price and need to find out where the break even point is, for example:

$\$54.61 - \$34.97 - \$11.45 - (0.15 \cdot \$54.61) = 0$

(Minimum Selling Price) - (Cost) - (Shipping) - (Fees) = 0

So at $\$54.61$, I would make $\$0.00$ on the product but I need a formula to figure out how to get to the $\$54.61$ number.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out....

$\frac{\text{Cost} + \text{Shipping}}{1 - \text{Fees}} = \text{Minimum Selling Price} $